# arithmetic mean of log returns that starts and ends with the same price in a time series

Tags: log-returns, mean

quick question:
arithmetic mean of log returns that starts and ends with the same price in a time series

say a stock time series starts at t0 price 100 fluctuates in between the time series and ends at tx 100. arithmetic mean of log returns is 0, correct?

I ask this bc R seems to suggest otherwise or result in conflicting results.

Comment: Does the asset in question pay dividends or not? If not and you start at $P_0$ and end up at $P_n=P_0$ then indeed the sum of log returns will be zero and so will the mean of log returns. If there are dividends then you may have made a positive return.

Comment: Hi: Note that the comment of @noob2 holds for log returns also. In fact, I don't think anything that the OP said hinges on the returns being arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick mental check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a arithmetic mean,

When P<sub>0</sub> = P<sub>t = end</sub>, then mean<sub>0 ~ t</sub> of returns = 0. Including log returns. For that matter, any returns.